# Usage of と particle

Tags: usage, particle-と

What is the function of the "と" particle in this sentence?

> 沢山手紙を書くからね,   と.

Comment: Would you give us some context? The person doesn't happen to be writing down these words as they utter them to themselves, do they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 沢山手紙{たくさんてがみ}を書{か}くからね, **と**。

＝

> 『沢山手紙を書くからね。』**と**。

≒

> 『沢山手紙を書くからね。』**と**言{い}った/思{おも}った/書{か}いた, etc.。

This is the **quotative 「と」**.

> Someone said/thought to himself/wrote, etc. "I will write you many letters!"

What the actual action is and who that someone is, only the context will tell.